# django.contrib.auth.models.User.customer.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no customer

Tags: django

```py
def cart(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete= False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()


    else:
        items = []
    context = {'items':items}
    return render(request,'store/cart.html', context)
```

That is my add to cart code that still display that there is no related object.

Comment: Add your models. Did you applies migrations? Does your `User` model have a `customer` field?

Comment: Well in that case, you probably should wrap that customer line in a `try/except AttributeError` and raise a 403 if it's not set. Even after you setup all the customer objects, that's still good practice to have the view ready to prevent a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

`User has no customer` means when you are calling `customer = request.user.customer`, the request user object has no related customer in your database.

Comment: sir i relly checked everything but there is no difference let me show you my Traceback: